# How except one value from a sum? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have this df and I want to add a new column "Sum" with the values of the sum bellow the column "Pij" with the same "periodo" and same "i"

```
 Periodo i  j       Pij           
0   1    1  1   0.298507    
1   1    1  2   0.253731    
2   1    1  3   0.447761    
3   1    2  2   0.843170    
4   1    2  1   0.134907    
5   1    2  3   0.021922
```

The result should be

```
 Periodo i  j       Pij      Sum    
0   1    1  1   0.298507    0.7014
1   1    1  2   0.253731    0.4477  
2   1    1  3   0.447761    0
3   1    2  2   0.843170    0.8650
4   1    2  1   0.134907    0.0219
5   1    2  3   0.021922    0
```

I have tried a groupby(["Periodo","i"]).cumsum()

Answer (score 2):

First change order of all rows (swap DataFrame rows by indexing in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)), then use lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and last again swap to original order by `iloc`:

```
df['Sum'] = (df.iloc[::-1]
               .groupby(["Periodo","i"])['Pij']
               .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
               .iloc[::-1])
print (df)
   Periodo  i  j       Pij       Sum
0        1  1  1  0.298507  0.701492
1        1  1  2  0.253731  0.447761
2        1  1  3  0.447761  0.000000
3        1  2  2  0.843170  0.156829
4        1  2  1  0.134907  0.021922
5        1  2  3  0.021922  0.000000
```